# How to check if an IP address corresponds to localhost in C

Tags: c, network-programming

In C on linux, is there a canonical way to check that an IP address corresponds to localhost?

That is, I'm looking for a function `is_localhost` such that if my computer has an external IP of "1.2.3.4", then calling `is_localhost` on any of "localhost", "127.0.0.1" or "1.2.3.4" should return true, and any other IP will return false.

On a side note, how difficult is it to spoof this information - does checking that the host is localhost in this way guarantee that the request actually came from this computer?

For context, I'm writing a management interface for a server.  I'd like to make the read-only management bits, like viewing a list of connections, available over the network, but for anything dangerous, like manually killing a connection, you should be doing it by running a script on the server itself.

Thanks!

Comment: An IP for your own computer (e.g, `1.2.3.4` in your example) is **not** the same as localhost -- that interface always has an IPv4 address in the `127.0.0.0/8` range. Do you actually mean localhost, or do you just mean "this computer"?

Comment: I would be very doubtful that there's a canonical way in C to check this, mainly because your machine has absolutely no control or influence over its external IP address. I'm not sure how `ifconfig` is able to do it so maybe it might be worth checking that out.

Comment: @duskwuff I just mean this computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be trying to solve your problem in the wrong way - If you want to restrict access to your remotely accessible application by checking if its the local host or not then checking the IP address would be a very bad way to do it. A PC can have any number of easily configurable network interfaces with IP addresses of your own choosing. So it would be very easy to work around.

You may want to look into adding some basic authentication or simply don't allow certain functions to be run remotely. There would be many ways to achieve this, but I think the scope of the question ends here with -- Don't rely on checking for the IP address. :)